# I just failed this "Review" test

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, link-only-answers

**EDIT: The point is the answer was NOT "low quality" - the QUESTION was! The answer PERFECTLY answers the question! Why do you guys not READ before voting??? Link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528665/international-weather-api-for-ruby-on-rails** Here is the question the answer is for: "*I'm looking for the best (free/cheap) international weather rails API out there. Any suggestions?*"

https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/6556729

...and I'm not satisfied with that test.

Okay, the answer is low quality (because the question is - the answer is actually a perfectly valid and good response!). I knew that, but I still defend my decision to click on "No Action Needed". Reason: I always look at what else is there, what other answers.

Looking at ALL the answers in that topic [(link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13528665/international-weather-api-for-ruby-on-rails) it is obvious (to me?) that the short answer that I was supposed to flag in that review is actually okay! The other answers are short too! And the accepted one is longer, but really does not have more than this one. And two other answers that have NOT been flagged(! - in two years) are just as short.

So I'd say this review question test is at the very least not an ideal review question. I'd *still* say it is okay to have that answer in there. I think that answer was wrongly flagged by people who didn't look at its context.

Comment: The question needs to be closed.

Comment: So if somebody posts a good answer next week then you'll retroactively change your review?  Audits should not be "ideal", if real posts were ideal then you would not be asked to review them.

Comment: If *the answer is low quality*, and you *knew that*, then **clearly** the proper review action was not "No Action Needed". Low quality answer means the opposite (action is **definitely** needed), and if you chose to take no action you correctly failed the review.

Comment: Q was: "I'm looking for the best (free/cheap) international weather rails API out there. Any suggestions?" THE ANSWER IS PERFECT!

Comment: The question is off-topic and should be closed (edit: already closed), thus making (almost) all answers low quality. (I said 'almost', because it's very rare to see brilliant answer on off-topic question)

Comment: Yes - that's my point: how can you blame the answer when it is the question? Given the Q the answer is NOT low quality. This is really bad to use for review-testing. Of course, everybody downvoted me because nobody cared to actually LOOK at the question, well done guys. Maybe a *little* more effort should be put into voting and testing.

Comment: Because off-topic question shouldn't be answered in the first place. Even if it hadn't been closed, but you knew it's off-topic, then the answer was low quality and should be removed. Conclusion: in current situation (after SO tightened its rule and policy), that kind of question shouldn't have answers, and shouldn't been asked.

Comment: @AndrewT. The QUESTION should have been removed, not the answer. The answer was perfectly suited as a response for the question. And the test was on the ANSWER, not on the question.

Answer (score 23):

> Okay, the answer is low quality. I knew that

Stop right there. That's all you needed to know to take proper action.

If there are *even worse* answers on the question, then you might want to take action on those too - or, if that's *the only sort of answer the question is able to attract,* flag or vote to close the whole thing.

But that doesn't change the fact that you were asked to review an answer, found it to be of poor quality, and did nothing.

Comment: Q: "I'm looking for the best (free/cheap) international weather rails API out there. Any suggestions?" How is the answer "low quality"? It is NOT! The question is! The answer is OKAY!!!

Comment: You might want to chill out a bit; your reaction is entirely disproportionate to what happened. Name-calling won't get you anywhere, by the way, it just makes it obvious that you have nothing useful to say. You need to admit that you made a mistake, apologise for this nonsense, and go about your day.

Comment: Since the answer was perfectly suited as a reply for the question, how did I make a mistake? What kind of "logic" rules your thoughts?

Comment: Mathematical logic, usually, but it varies based on the input. Look, you can either keep the combative "I'm right, you're all wrong" stance that you've got going on here, or you can try to be a bit more pleasant, realise that you've fallen short of the community's expectations in this particular instance, and move on with your life in a positive frame of mind. You might find the latter of those options to be more productive in the long run. But it's really up to you. Just don't expect people to keep engaging with you if you keep up your current approach.

Comment: Regardless of whether the answer was *valid* or not, it was a poor answer @Mörre - you admitted this yourself. Being a valid answer rules out certain actions, but certainly not all of them - you could have left a comment, downvoted, edited.. Really, anything that might've improved the situation *even a little bit*.

Comment: Eh... what??? My "admission" was a mistake, after reviewing the whole thing. Also, the reason for posting this on "meta" had NOTHING to do with my "failure" (I mean, who cares? It does not even have consequences on this website, and even if it did, I don't care about some random website that I can create a new account on any time). I posted it on "meta" to HELP - in this case to help weed out an item that I'm now even more convinced than before is an unfortunate choice for a review test.

Comment: And my purpose in answering is only to help you understand why this *is* a reasonable audit, @Mörre. If it helps, you were the third person to receive it as an audit and to date the *only* person to choose "No Action Needed". Additionally, when it was originally posted, it was reviewed in both the Late Answers and Low Quality review queues - out of a combined 7 reviewers in both of those queues, no one thought it was acceptable. It is probably one of the more clear-cut audits out there.